# What time standards are these?

Tags: time, timezone, timestamp

Frustration over conversions between time zones and time standards seem to be a shared experience among programmers, and I'm finally joining the club. Can you help me recognize these three formats so I can look them up?

```
0325.09:58:27.944

1407337254

20140806 10:59:54
```

I realize this may not be enough to go on, since it's hard to tell the difference between months and days and so on, but hopefully the punctuation is enough to identify at least the first format.

Comment: Do you mean are they following some named standard? Or just how to decode them?

Comment: Oh, and you said "these two" but posted three; do they all represent the same time with the last as a reference?

Comment: The second format is a [Unix timestamp](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time): the number of seconds between midnight 1st Jan 1970 and about 3o'clock this afternoon. The first is clearly just before 10am, with the last digits presumably fractional seconds (milliseconds), but I'm not sure what the 0325 represents.

Comment: Thanks! I had two, but added another and forgot to change it; I'll do that now.

Comment: The reason I thought the third format might be for reference is that it's very simple to decode  - YYYYMMDD hh:mm:ss - is there some reason you think it's a named standard and want to know what it is?

Comment: It might not be a standard; it's possible it's just a pretty string output from the programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of these are compliant with standards, however you can deduce what they might represent.

> 0325.09:58:27.944

This one is tricky, as it `0325` could represent any of:

- March 25th of some unknown year
- The 325th day after some unknown epoch
- 325 days of elapsed duration

Though it would be somewhat odd to have a leading zero in anything but the March 25th option.

> 1407337254

This is a "UNIX Timestamp".  [You can read about them on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_timestamp).  This one is equivalent to Wed, 06 Aug 2014 15:00:54 GMT.  [epochconverter.com](http://www.epochconverter.com/) is a good site for quick manipulation of these values.

Note, while UNIX Timestamps are a common convention, they are not a *standard*.  There is no RFC or other spec from IETF, W3C, ISO, ECMA, or other standards body that describes the standards for UNIX timestamps.

> 20140806 10:59:54

The first part is a year in YYYYMMDD format.  The second part is a time in HH:MM:SS format.  This is close to [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso8601), however:

- There is usually a `T` separating the date and time components, though the spec does allow for it to be omitted "by mutual agreement".
- It's not valid to mix the basic and extended forms.  You might have `2014-08-06T10:59:54`, or `20140806T105954`, but not the mix that you are showing here.